# JSON.parse() is giving unexpected error : "Unexpected end of JSON input"

Tags: node.js, json, api, express, https

**console.log(d); gives the following output (hexadecimal code):**

<Buffer 7b 22 73 75 63 63 65 73 73 22 3a 74 72 75 65 2c 22 64 61 74 61 22 3a 7b 22 73 75 6d 6d 61 72 79 22 3a 7b 22 74 6f 74 61 6c 22 3a 31 39 39 32 35 36 30 ... 293 more bytes>

<Buffer 6f 62 61 72 20 49 73 6c 61 6e 64 73 22 2c 22 63 6f 6e 66 69 72 6d 65 64 43 61 73 65 73 49 6e 64 69 61 6e 22 3a 36 30 38 34 2c 22 63 6f 6e 66 69 72 6d ... 1319 more bytes>
<Buffer 43 61 73 65 73 49 6e 64 69 61 6e 22 3a 35 39 34 36 30 31 2c 22 63 6f 6e 66 69 72 6d 65 64 43 61 73 65 73 46 6f 72 65 69 67 6e 22 3a 31 2c 22 64 69 73 ... 1319 more bytes>

<Buffer 38 2c 22 63 6f 6e 66 69 72 6d 65 64 43 61 73 65 73 46 6f 72 65 69 67 6e 22 3a 33 2c 22 64 69 73 63 68 61 72 67 65 64 22 3a 33 39 38 31 36 35 38 2c 22 ... 1319 more bytes>

<Buffer 61 6c 43 6f 6e 66 69 72 6d 65 64 22 3a 31 32 30 37 31 31 32 7d 2c 7b 22 6c 6f 63 22 3a 22 54 65 6c 61 6e 67 61 6e 61 22 2c 22 63 6f 6e 66 69 72 6d 65 ... 740 more bytes>

**When I try to convert this into JSON using JSON.parse(d), I get the following error:**

undefined:1

{"success":true,"data":{"summary":{"total":19925604,"confirmedCasesIndian":19925556,"confirmedCasesForeign":48,"discharged":16293003,"deaths":218959,"confirmedButLocationUnidentified":0},"unofficial-summary":[{"source":"covid19india.org","total":7945975,"recovered":7198877,"deaths":119538,"active":626192}],"regional":[{"loc":"Andaman and Nicoba

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (E:\Web Development\Test\app.js:16:24)

at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:315:20)

at IncomingMessage.Readable.read (internal/streams/readable.js:519:10)

at flow (internal/streams/readable.js:992:34)

at resume_ (internal/streams/readable.js:973:3)

at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
```

**Here is my app.js file code:**

```
const express = require("express");
const https = require("https");

const app = express();


app.get("/", (req, res) => {

  const url = "https://api.rootnet.in/covid19-in/stats/latest";

  https.get(url, function(response) {
    console.log(response.statusCode);

    response.on("data", (d) => {

      console.log(JSON.parse(d));
      // console.log(d);

    })

  res.send()

  })



})



app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("server up and running at port 3000");
})
```

Comment: `response.on("data", (d) => { console.log(JSON.parse(d)); }` - `d` is a "chunk" of data, you might not have received the full data in one chunk, but you're trying to parse it. If it's not the full json payload then parsing will fail because it's not valid json. Wait for the "end" event, then combine the buffers and parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method .on("data") receives chunks of buffers, you need to concat that buffers once receiving is finished, convert to string and then parse to JSON.

```
https.get(url, function(response) {
    const data = [];
    response.on("data", (d) => {
        data.push(d);
    }).on('end', function() {
        //at this point data is an array of Buffers
        //so Buffer.concat() can make us a new Buffer
        //of all of them together
        const buffer = Buffer.concat(data);
        const obj = JSON.parse(buffer.toString());
        console.log(obj);
    });
})
```

Comment: Console.log() gives a weird output I am expecting a JSON output like : {
"success": true,
"data": {
"summary": {
"total": 19925604,
"confirmedCasesIndian": 19925556,
"confirmedCasesForeign": 48,
"discharged": 16293003,
"deaths": 218959,
"confirmedButLocationUnidentified": 0
},

Comment: but I get this type of output:

Comment: {type: 'Buffer',data: [123,  34, 115, 117,  99,  99, 101, 115, 115,  34,  58, 116,
    114, 117, 101,  44,  34, 100,  97, 116,  97,  34,  58, 123,
     34, 115, 117, 109, 109,  97, 114, 121,  34,  58, 123,  34,
    116, 111, 116,  97, 108,  34,  58,  49,  57,  57,  50,  53,
     54,  48,  52,  44,  34,  99, 111, 110, 102, 105, 114, 109,
    101, 100,  67,  97, 115, 101, 115,  73, 110, 100, 105,  97,
    110,  34,  58,  49,  57,  57,  50,  53,  53,  53,  54,  44,
     34,  99, 111, 110, 102, 105, 114, 109, 101, 100,  67,  97,
    115, 101, 115,  70,
    ... 236 more items]
}

Comment: My mistake... now I get it, please check my updated answer

Comment: Why do I need to do all of this because when I open the API link(https://api.rootnet.in/covid19-in/stats/latest), The data is a JSON file? Why can't I just get the Hexa coded JSON object and convert it directly using JSON.parse()?

Comment: Is it because the data is very large that I need to do this ?

Comment: Should I use another module instead of HTTPS?

Comment: That's not because of large data... That is how .on("data") method works, It receives chunks of data, not all the data at once, and the on("end") listener fires when the request is finished.

You can use axios, I think it's the most used and it's good

Comment: plea vote up my answer if you think it's useful

Comment: I already did, but how was I supposed to know about better libraries are available than HTTPS which I learned in an online course, I am new to back end development

Answer (score 0):

Even though the question is about [https](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html)

To make things easier, may I suggest to use [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) (and/or [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)) instead of https, since it's commonly used (and easier since you don't have to check for start or end of data).

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch')

......

const results = await fetch(url).then(res => res.json());
console.log(results)
```

Comment: how am I supposed to know every better library than the libraries I use which I learned in an online course. Can you suggest or help me with how should I know that this library is better and easier to implement. and where can I find such better libraries, I mean what should I google for stuff like this. PS: I am new to backend development

Comment: If you don't know, then use what i suggested. `node-fetch` or `axios`. I've provided the sample code in my answer. You will get to know common libraries you use as you start to code more, and start to research more on what you intend to do. At this moment of time, you want to learn how to fetch data from url and you know about `node-fetch` and `axios` :)